# Web API post authentication to SQL Server with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, http-post

I used C# to do `GET()` SQL Server data for iOS to read json data. Now I want to do a function to verify the account password. iOS uses the `POST()` method on the API to verify the id and password in the SQL Server table.

POST function I only need to compare SQL Server, return TRUE OR FALSE.

I do not know what to do.

This is my `GET` C# code:

```
public object Get()
{
        using (appapidataEntities entities = new appapidataEntities())
        {
            var SQLjsonndata = entities.USERs.ToList();

            return new
            {
                USER = SQLjsonndata
            };

        }
}
```

Json output :

```
{  
   "USER":[  
      {  
         "ID":"1",
         "Password":"mo"
      },
      {  
         "ID":"111112",
         "Password":"7776"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public object Post(parameters)
{
        using (appapidataEntities entities = new appapidataEntities())
        {
            var result = entities.StoredProedureForPost(ParaMetersForStoredProcedure);
            return result
        }
}
```

Comment: create object for your entity model and then call some SP to insert the values.